# Bootstrap shadow container width too wide for large view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm new to bootstrap (less than six hours of docs/dev time) and I have an issue where the width for my shadow container extends too wide relative to smaller screen sizes. Any view above 991px leaves unsightly whitespace to the right of the form.

I have a [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/hMzGDp9oBH) illustrating this with all of the code I'm using.

Any help or guidance to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 10:

> '<'div class="col-lg-8 order-md-1>

Col-lg-8 was defined...

According to the grid system...

For resolution ≥992px, the LG class prefix becomes active.

With that, you started using 8/12 of the width...

Appearing 3/12 on the right side in white.

If you want to use full width at that resolution, set col-lg-12.

> '<'div class="col-lg-12 order-md-1">

Hope this helps.